# App that allows a deaf person to record the conversation with a hearing person

Tags: gratis, ios, iphone-app, communication, accessibility

I am deaf and I am searching for an app that allows me to have a conversation with a hearing person using iPhone 6c iOS 9.2.1.

It will help me if I need to talk with a person and not having a "live" sign language interpreter present in the event of emergency.

I am looking for a free one.

Comment: There are *many* audio-recording apps available for iOS including one bundled by Apple (“Voice Memos). What are your special needs? Your question is not clear. Your title talks about recording yet the body of your question may be suggesting a translator or writer. Please explain.

Comment: @PROBERT:  Anything you have to say about such applications, either learned or desired, is appreciated.  See http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/28605/app-to-help-hard-of-hearing-hoh-for-phone-calls-conversations-public-lectures

Comment: @PROBERT: I agree you should make it clearer what you want.  I'm guessing you want speech-to-text,  not speech capture ("record the conversation").